# How old is the Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: ancient-greece, geometry, ancient-egypt, pythagorean-proposition

More specifically, what is the oldest evidence of human awareness of what we now call the Pythagorean Theorem?

The phrase, "evidence of human awareness" was used to exclude a different question of when was the first proof made.  It also constrains answers to those based on artifacts.  (Artifacts form the basis of our knowledge of ancient history.)  Each artifact can have different interpretations.  The dates of the artifacts have errors/uncertainties.  So, the question boils down to, of all the artifacts ever in existence, which probably has the earliest date that also is good evidence of a human being aware of the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: There are two possible questions here, and they have different answers: (1) When was the Pythagorean theorem _proved?_ and (2) when was the Pythagorean theorem known and assumed to probably be true without proof?

Comment: I disagree due to your usage of "here".  IMO, my actual question above is just #2, not #1.  That said, I'd guess a proof was discovered near the same time.

Comment: Please refer to the rules, how to ask questions on this site.

Comment: Babylonians developed the theorem "at least fifteen hundred years before Pythagoras was born." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#History

Comment: Wilhelm, that's false. There's a huge difference between a source saying *x* is true vs. a source saying person *y* claims *x* is true. The sentence there is, "Other sources, such as a book by ... Teresi, mention that Pythagoras discovered the theorem,[72] although Teresi subsequently stated that the Babylonians developed the theorem "at least fifteen hundred years before Pythagoras was born."[73]" This does *not* say your fragment is verified by the wikipedia community, as you implied. Worse, the sentence actually pokes fun of the authors because it is largely self contradictory.

Comment: In other words, a more correct interpretation of the full sentence is that the collective wikipedia community thinks that a person who has claimed the fragment's meaning is not very credible.  This is actually the opposite of what you implied.

Comment: Prof. Eremenko, you imply but do not state that I've violated "the rule"(s) of this site, yet you fail to give enough specificity for your comment to have substantive utility. Concurrent to your comment, the question was downvoted.  Don't be so passive aggressive; prey tell, what rules, exactly, do you think I've violated?

Comment: Thanks for the link to "How to Ask."  That said, I fail to see anything of relevance. 
 Moreover, I also fail to see anything unclear.  Even so, I will explain the question in more detail in the hopes of getting the hold status removed.